# where does array declared local to a function will be in memory?

Tags: java, arrays

I read that local variables are in stack memory.And, array is saved in heap memory. So what if i have declared an array local to a block or function? where does that array gets saved? please help me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse the array with the *reference* to the array, which is what you declare in the method body. The reference is inside the method invocation frame ("on the stack"), but the array itself is dynamically allocated, as everything else in Java. The JIT compiler may conclude that it will pay off to allocate a small array directly on the stack, but that goes into the "advanced" category and is certainly outside your control.

Comment: dynamically allocated? i thought array is also known as "static data structure". so its size is well pre defined. right? did you mean that, the memory location is dynamically allocated?

Comment: The memory block holding the array's contents is dynamically allocated. Array's size is not statically determined, it is a dynamic parameter at runtime. What you had in mind is that an array cannot be resized.

Answer (score 2):

The array is stored in the heap. I don't believe escape analysis can allocate it on the stack like some objects can be.

The *reference* to the array could be on the stack.

Comment: I think there is actually a threshold for stack-allocating small arrays.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I just tried 1, 4 and 8 bytes arrays but no luck.  I know varargs can be eliminated but I think that is different.

Comment: I have a faint recollection of it, so I could easily be wrong. It may have been in the context of a proposal for a future implementation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it could also be I didn't do the exact option which has been optimised. It can be tricky to find a simple example which doesn't just suffer Dead Code elimination, but is simple enough to be optimised.